# Getting CurrentRecord from a table in a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a company form that list their basic info with a subform tab that list more company info like contacts, parts and orders. I use a tab control where each tab has a table with basic info about each. I am trying to open another form that has detailed information about the user highlighted row in the table, but cannot figure out how to read which row is selected.

The form is call Customer, the tab form is called tabDetails, the parts tab is caled tabParts and the table that lists all the parts for the company is called tblPartsList.

This is what I thought would work.

```
ID = Me!tabDetails!tabParts!tblPartsList!CurrentRecord![ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found to work was just to call the table control.

```
ID = tblPartsList![ID]
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Form property of the subform control.

*tabDetails* here is the name of the subform *control*:

```
ID = Me!tabDetails.Form![ID].Value
```

or:

```
ID = Me!tabDetails.Form!tblPartsList.[ID].Value
```

The form's tabs are only for ordering the controls. They are not containers for these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ActiveControl** property to refer to the control that has the focus at runtime

`ID= Screen.ActiveControl.Parent("ID")`